# Is there a way to pass a value to a specific item in a constructor?

Tags: java

I'm sorry if this is a very basic but I couldn't find anything in my books and searching.  I am trying to send information when creating an object but there's many options and I only really to change one(unfortunately, its near the end).

Say I have something like this:

```
class_to_start_(int maxActive, 
    byte whenExhaustedAction, 
    long maxWait, 
    int maxIdle, 
    int minIdle, 
    boolean testOnBorrow, 
    boolean testOnReturn, 
    long timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis, 
    int numTestsPerEvictionRun, 
    long minEvictableIdleTimeMillis, 
    boolean testWhileIdle, 
    long softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis, 
    boolean lifo)
```

They all have default values so I don't need to change any of them, but I want to modify the default value of the last one `lifo` only.  Can I do it without sending values to all others? Ideally something like `class_to_start_('lifo'=True)` (this doesn't work, I tried it).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't have default parameter values, so the short answer is no.

You can have overloaded constructors however, so that you have a constructor that just takes the argument you want to change:

```
/** Main constructor. */
public Foo(int maxActive, 
           byte whenExhaustedAction, 
           int minIdle, 
           boolean testOnBorrow, 
           boolean lifo) 

/** Convenience constructor. */
public Foo(boolean lifo)
{
  this(1, 0x01, 3, false, lifo);    // call the main constructor will default values
}
```

You could also look at making a [fluent interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html) builder object.  The idea then would be you do:

```
final Foo f = new FooBuilder().withLifo(false).build();
```

Comment: doesn't this mean I still need to put in the default arguments if I only want to change the last one?

Comment: You have to supply the default values *somewhere*, yes.

Comment: @learningJava: Are *you* writing the `Foo` class, or is this an existing class you're just using?

Comment: Its an existing class I'm using.  Provided by another library.

Comment: @learningJava: that's not clear from your question, and pretty much everyone is answering expecting that you're writing the object in question.

Comment: @learningJava: Since you're not writing the class, then you're pretty much stuck with what they gave you.  One option is to write a wrapper factory ...

Answer (score 0):

What also could work is to create one instance of your desired class and set all values to your desired default values:

```
// in your main method
Foo myDefaults = new Foo(100, "name", false, true);
myDefaults.setLifo(false);
Foo someChangedInstance = myDefaults;
```

...then add a constructor to your class that takes an instance of the class and sets all values equal to the values of the parametered instance:

```
// in your Foo class
public Foo(int maxWidth, String standardName, boolean logEverything, boolean lifo) {
    // ...
}

public Foo(Foo otherInstance) {
    this.maxWidth = otherInstance.maxWidth;
    this.standardName = otherInstance.standardName;
    this.logEverything = otherInstance.logEverything;
    this.lifo = otherInstance.lifo;
}
```

That way you can modify only single values of the instance of your class and create new instances with only some modifications.

Don't forget to probably reset the attributes in myDefault after changing them.

```
myDefault.setLifo(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constructor that takes a Map of parameter and value pairs, and use the defaults for any parameters not specified.  That way you only need to specify the parameters you want to override.

Answer (score 0):

When the default values are typically used, and there are a lot of parameters, using a constructor or a factory method becomes clumsy. The most convenient and elegant approach is to use setters with a [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Java).

Like this:

public class MyClass {

```
// Define default values in initializers
private int maxActive = 5;
private byte whenExhaustedAction = 'x';
private long maxWait = 999;
private int maxIdle = 3;
private int minIdle = 1;
private boolean testOnBorrow = true;
private boolean testOnReturn = false;
private long timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000;
private  int numTestsPerEvictionRun = 10;
private  long minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 2000;
private boolean testWhileIdle = false;
private long softMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 0;
private  boolean lifo = true; 

// Only getter/setters for first two fields shown - others similar

public int getMaxActive() {
    return maxActive;
}

// Return "this" to create a fluent interface
public MyClass setMaxActive(int maxActive) {
    this.maxActive = maxActive;
    return this;
}

public int getMaxIdle() {
    return maxIdle;
}

public MyClass setMaxIdle(int maxIdle) {
    this.maxIdle = maxIdle;
    return this;
}

// Other getters/setters to follow
```

}

Use it like this, only calling the setters of the fields where you want a value other than the default:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass().setMaxActive(5).setMaxIdle(100);
```